# Is it possible to execute more than one CUDA graph's host execution node in different streams concurrently?

Tags: cuda, synchronization, gpgpu, cuda-streams, cuda-graphs

Investigating possible solutions for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75726509/is-there-a-way-to-block-and-unblock-a-cuda-stream-arbitrarily) problem, I thought about using CUDA graphs' host execution nodes (`cudaGraphAddHostNode`). I was hoping to have the option to block and unblock streams on the host side instead of the device side with the wait kernel, while still using graphs.

I made a test program with two graphs. One graph does a host-to-device copy, calls a host function (with a host execution node) that waits in a loop for the "event" variable to stop being equal to `0` (i.e. waits for the "event"), then does a device-to-host copy. Another graph does a memset on the device memory, then calls a host function that sets the "event" variable to `1` (i.e. signals the "event"). I launch the first graph on one stream, the second on another, then synchronize on the first stream.

The result was that both graphs were launched as expected, the "wait" host function was executed, and the first stream was blocked successfully. However, even though the second graph was launched, the "signal" host function was never executed.

I realized that CUDA's implementation is likely serializing all host execution nodes in the context, so the "signal" node is forever waiting for the "wait" node to finish before executing. The documentation is even saying that "host functions without a mandated order (such as in independent streams) execute in undefined order and **may be serialized**".

I also tried launching the graphs from separate host threads, but that didn't work.

Is there some kind of way to make host execution nodes on different streams concurrent that I'm missing?

Comment: Why not start a new thread/task inside the host callback?

Comment: @paleonix The point is to synchronize two graphs and the streams they were launched on, as I explained in the linked question. I don't think I understand how starting a new thread/task inside the first host callback can help that, could you please elaborate?

Comment: No, you are right. The waiting one can't be asynchronous because you want to synchronize and while the second one can, it would not help if it never gets launched.

Comment: Maybe you can do the waiting inside a kernel, with the event variable in global memory?

Comment: Yes, that was the answer proposed in the item OP linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't a reliable method.  It is [evident](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164942/what-thread-runs-the-callback-passed-to-cudastreamaddcallback) that additional thread(s) are spun up by the CUDA runtime to handle host callbacks, but there is no detail or specification.

In order for such a thing to work, you would need the two synchronizing agents to each have their own thread, running concurrently.  That way, if the waiting agent spun up first, the signaling agent would still be able to execute and deliver a signal.

But for `cudaLaunchHostFunc` (and we can surmise the same thing with graph host nodes) it is [explicitly stated](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g05841eaa5f90f27124241baafb3e856f):

> Host functions without a mandated order (such as in independent streams) execute in undefined order and **may be serialized**.

(*emphasis added*)

Serialization of host functions would make such a scheme not workable.

> Is there some kind of way to make host execution nodes on different streams concurrent that I'm missing?

There aren't any additional controls or specification for this, that I am aware of.